# Why is this question deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

The question has been deleted without any feedback.

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/61931/how-different-and-similar-are-laws-against-narcotic-in-indonesia-and-us-and-port

I am asking what Article 128(3) from the Indonesian narcotic's law means.  One way to see it is to compare the differences between that law and law in Portugal. In Portugal people have to register that they use drugs and then they get a light penalty.

I wonder if that law in Indonesia is like that in Portugal. If not what's the difference? Has Indonesia decriminalized drug usage?

It's pretty practical. If it's true then any user should just register and be free from penalty. If not, then why?

Why is it deleted?

Should I modify the question?

Comment: Do you mean this question where you asked the meaning of Article 128(3) back in September 2019: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/44445/is-this-true-that-drug-users-in-indonesia-cannot-be-prosecuted-if-they-are-in-re   If so, you accepted a very clear and accurate answer (but there's no mention of Portugal so I may be wrong..?)

Comment: if you want to discuss a deleted question, you need to link to the deleted question. I can not find any question with the words Indonesia, Drug or Portoguese [since march 26th.](https://law.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last30days)

Comment: I've voted to reopen now the relevant question has been linked.

Comment: @RockApe the question is similar. However the latter questions is on the difference. I just received info that to get treatment you actually have to use drugs first in Indonesia. So it's kind of strange that to get something positive from the government you got to break the law first. If a person has not used drugs for 1 years and want to get treatment for drug addiction, he will have to (illegally) use drugs first and got tested positive first. Is this the same with in Portugal? Is it really the way it is? That sort of thing. That's what I want to know.

Comment: Of course, being Indonesian, the info that I got is either you have to illegaly use drugs first and get tested positive to get treatment. Or you can bribe. Either case you got to break the law. That's the nuance I want to understand in Indonesia. Either the narcotic department is very corrupt of the lawyer is lying. Both are very plausible in Indonesia.

Answer (score 4):

Your question was deleted by the [Roomba](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/roomba), an automatic process that removes questions that meet certain conditions (this link appears on the word "deleted" at the top of your question).  In this case, your question met the `RemoveAbandonedClosed` condition described on that page, as it was closed, unanswered, did not have a positive score or reopen votes, and had not been recently edited.

---

Perhaps you're wondering why it was *closed* in the first place.  Your biggest problem is it lacks focus—you've asked multiple questions, some of which (comparing *all* the differences between areas of law) are quite broad themselves.  You've also asked for this comparison between *three* countries.  You could probably write a book on the topic—it's too much for a single question/answer on Stack Exchange.

You've also asked a few opinion-based questions, like *why* the law sets the penalties the way they do.  These sorts of "why did politicians enact the laws that they did?" questions are off-topic here, but *may* be on-topic at [Politics Stack Exchange](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  You'll want to read that link before asking there, though.

In summary, you should stick to a single, fact-based question about what the law is (or was in the past).

---

Finally, you ask if you should modify the question.  If you want it to be answered, you'll definitely need to address the reasons it was closed, but since it's already been deleted, [you should just ask a new question with the problems fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310266/165261).  Trying to get a question undeleted is far more hassle than it's worth when there's no answers worth preserving.  Just make sure that you've actually addressed the problems and aren't simply re-asking more or less the same question.